# Find the slant area of a cone

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question: Find the slant curved area of the surface of revolution of a cone of semi-vertical angle $\alpha$ and base circle of radius a by revolving about the X-axis.**

I tried using $ r=a \csc \theta $ and integrating from $\theta=0$ to $ \theta=\alpha$, but the answer is wrong.

Help me with the correct equation and the limits.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you expect the answer to be $\pi r^2a/3$?

Comment: The answer is stated to be pi*(a^2)*cosec alpha

Comment: @NoChance He is not talking about cone volume but cone slant area.

Comment: @Narasimham, got it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful to look to what you are integrating.

Consider a differential triangular area in yellow color on the slant side as shown:

[image]

$$ dA= \frac12 \frac{a}{\sin \alpha} a \, d \theta $$

Integrating

$$ \int dA = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac12 \frac{a}{\sin \alpha} a \, d \theta = \frac{\pi a^2}{\sin \alpha}.$$

Also see how the standard slant area formula $ A = \pi a L $ is derived with $ L= \dfrac{a}{\sin \alpha}. $

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Whe need to use the general formula for the area of a [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution)

$$S= 2\pi\cdot\int_a^b f(x)\cdot \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$$

that is by

- $f(x)=\tan \alpha \cdot x \implies f'(x)=\tan \alpha$
- $a=0 \quad b=a\cot \alpha$

$$S= 2\pi\cdot\int_0^{a\cot \alpha} \tan \alpha \cdot x\cdot \sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha}dx$$

[image]

As an alternative and very effective way is use [Pappus's Centroid Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html).

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure the function I used was correct.

Comment: @VishalDalwadi There was a typo in the main formula which I've fixed! I've also added some more detail for the function to be used and the set up of the integral by the standard method for surface of revolution.